# Do I have to put `SetTitleMatchMode` on top of the script?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, script, automation, autohotkey, hotkeys

Sample script:

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
#SingleInstance Force

#IfWinActive Foo ahk_exe foo.exe
  !A::Send Foo

SetTitleMatchMode Regex

#IfWinActive Bar$ ahk_exe bar.exe
  !A::Send Bar
```

When running it, it throws:

[image]

I want to apply `SetTitleMatchMode Regex` only to `bar.exe`, is it achievable without putting it on top of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your script, but the answer is that you don't have to
place it at the top. It will affect all following commands until a `return`.

Proof of concept script:

```
F1::
   MsgBox, This should give 1`nA_TitleMatchMode=%A_TitleMatchMode%
   SetTitleMatchMode, 2
   MsgBox, This should give 2`nA_TitleMatchMode=%A_TitleMatchMode%
   SetTitleMatchMode, regex
   MsgBox, This should give regex`nA_TitleMatchMode=%A_TitleMatchMode%
return

F2::
   MsgBox, This should give 1`nA_TitleMatchMode=%A_TitleMatchMode%
return
```

To be convinced, run the above and press consecutively
<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Each key-press starts a new thread, so `SetTitleMatchMode` is
re-initialized to `1`.

---

`SetTitleMatchMode` is redundant.
Your code should look like (I didn't test):

```
#NOEnv
#Warn
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode Regex

!A::
if WinActive("Foo ahk_exe foo.exe")
  MsgBox, Foo
if WinActive("Bar$ ahk_exe bar.exe")
  MsgBox, Bar
```

Comment: I want `#IfWinActive Foo ahk_exe foo.exe` to use `SetTitleMatchMode 1`, and `#IfWinActive Bar$ ahk_exe bar.exe` to use `SetTitleMatchMode Regex`, is that achievable?

Comment: Yes, put the `SetTitleMatchMode` after the `#IfWinActive`.

Comment: I changed the code to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7SFt.png), but it throws [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU6go.png).

Comment: You have two lines for `SetTitleMatchMode Regex`, the first is giving the error and is redundant. **But** note that the [#IfWinActive documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) says: "The #IfWin directives are positional: they affect all **hotkeys and hotstrings** physically beneath them in the script", so it's useless for you. I think you should be using [WinActive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm) instead of `#IfWinActive`. `WinActive` is executive, while `#IfWinActive` is declarative.

Comment: [The image I attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7SFt.png) is a diff editor, so there's only one `SetTitleMatchMode Regex`. And I've changed the code to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luwcz.png), now it throws [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgyMT.png).

Comment: The error is correct: You can't *declare* the key `!A` twice. You should declare it only once, then use `if WinActive(...`. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: But I have to use `SetTitleMatchMode Regex`, otherwise, the hotkey can be triggered in the wrong dialog of `bar.exe`.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood and changed my example. There's no point in limiting the regex mode to one `if` if it's not used in the other. Note that title searches are case-sensitive, except when using the `i)` modifier in a RegEx pattern. See the examples in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, but the question's purpose is to limit the regex mode to _only_ one `if` without putting `SetTitleMatchMode` at the top, is that doable?

Comment: Yes, as I showed above, the `SetTitleMatchMode` command is positional (bearing in mind that a new thread is started for each detected hotkey).

Comment: Thanks, I've learned so much!